# Use React CDN and Django on same server and port

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, create-react-app

I'm using django for the backend and render the webUI from the django templates.
Now I wanted to dive into React and migrate to a client side rendered UI.
My idea is to setup django to only load the first (index.html) page where all the react cdn scripts (react, reactDOM, react-router, prop-types, axios, ...) and component scripts are loaded and their state will then be handled on the client machine.

My idea was to reduce the load on the application server due to the fact that the app server will have to handle a lot of concurrent users, a lot of api hits, input-ouput operations, high CPU consumption, handle multiple tcp connections, have high RAM usage which will accumulated take up a lot of resources.

For that reason I didn't want to build a react app and run it on the same machine on a dedicated port, because it will run next to the django application and take up RAM resources.

But the problem with the cdn variant of react is that I don't know how to use all the other modules that are pre-delivered when creating a react app `create-react-app`: prop-types, axios, and many more.

Do I have to import their respective cdn scripts each or can I bundle them later for production? How would you go about that approach?

Unfortunately there are only a few tutorials and those talk about using on same server on different ports and connecting via CORS. That's not what I want.

I'm thankful for any suggestions